OmniScript Integration Procedures doesn't work for community users
We implemented the Discovery Framework with Experience Users and we want to run Integration procedures with Decision Tables to pre-populate answers from previous forms.
It works fine for internal users, but there seemed to be some permission issues with Experience Users and since it's happening in the Managed Package it doesn't give any meaningful error.
Has someone done a similar implementation and can give a hint into what might be wrong?

did you managed to resolve your issue pls ?

the main issue was missing assignment for OmniScript license and Sharing/Object Level permission for related Assessment, OmniScript Objects

I think the initial issue was with missing license for OmniScript assigned to Users.
You can sometimes render OmniScript without license, but you always need to run Integration Procedures.
If it still doesn't work, then double-check permission for ALL Assessment Related Objects and OmniScript related Objects.
If it still doesn't work then make Sharing Settings Public Read/Write for all mentioned objects and then slowly remove those until you find a working balance.
Here is our final Sharing Setup:


Public Read for OmniScripts also should work
